# How can I evenly distribute UIButtons in swift using PureLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I am programmatically creating a UIView that loops through a set of strings and creates buttons for them. I wish to evenly space them in that view.

```
func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [NSString]) -> UIView {

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    var rowView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))

    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{
        let button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
        buttons.append(button)
        rowView.addSubview(button)
    }

    //Below will be replaced with PureLayout
    addConstraints(buttons, mainView: rowView)

    return rowView
}
```

The `addConstraints` function uses `NSLayoutContraint`. I'd like to replace with PureLayout but when I do buttons.autoDistributeViewsAlongAxis.... i get an error that UIButton does not have a member named autoDistributeViewsAlongAxis.

So, I get that it needs to be an array but as far as I can tell I've created an array of buttons in swift.

Any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: The PureLayout API you're interested in is a category on NSArray. Since you have a Swift array, you need to make it an NSArray: `let buttonsArray: NSArray = buttons`. Then you can call the PureLayout methods on `buttonsArray` since it is of type NSArray: `buttonsArray.autoDistributeViewsAlongAxis(...)` etc

Comment: I've just added a helper class for doing just that, it's written in Swift so it might make things easier for you, you can check it out on github: https://github.com/chrisben/DistributeViewsEvenly-Swift